# Can I send a SMS using Expo without the sender seeing the recipients phone number?

Tags: react-native, expo, sms

I am developing an app that will be used in an office to notify staff when a client is in the waiting room. The app will send a notification to specific staff with a button press. I've tried Expo SMS but this shows the recipients number which needs to be kept private. Is there a way to keep the recipients number hidden with Expo SMS or another library? Is it possible to show the sender a random number instead of the recipients actual number?

Any help would be appreciated.